# Passing two models in one go?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In my current View, I am passing a model like so:

Controller One

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var Item = from a in db.MyDatabase
               where a.UserId.Equals(UserId)
               select a;
    return View(Item.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

View One

```
@model Project.Models.Item
```

And I have another View that receives some other model, specifically from the Asp.Net User Roles

Controller Two

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var RoleMan = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var Roles = RoleMan.Roles;
    return View(Roles);
}
```

View Two

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>
```

In my new (Third) View, how can I combine or send both those models? So that I can use them both in my View?

Comment: I'm guessing all four of the downvotes are from the ridiculous and unnecessary emoti-things.  This isn't kindergarten.

Answer (score 1):

Make a third model class containing instances of the previous two model classes.

Also those emoticons are in very poor taste, this is a professional Q&A site, not a Kakao Talk forum.